# Rails and remote form using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am really stuck creating a remote => true form in rails 4.It seems that every time I fix an issue, something else breaks.

I am using simple_form and the following is my form code:

```
#agent_confirm_modal.small.reveal-modal{"data-reveal" => ""}
= simple_form_for  [:customer, @agent_confirm], :url => create_agent_confirm_customers_path, remote: true, html: {class: :ajax_form, :'data-type' => 'json'} do |f|
    .row
        .sub-headline-secondary
            .padding-16-balanced-bottom
                = "Agent Confirmation"

        .error

        .col-1-1-1.padding-16-all

            .padding-12-bottom
                = f.input :detail_verification, as: :boolean, label: "I have confirmed/updated the customer's details"

            .padding-12-bottom
                = f.input :document_verification, as: :boolean, label: "I have confirmed/updated the customer's documentation"

            %a.close-reveal-modal= "&#215;".html_safe

        .padding-16-all.margin-gutter-bottom
            = f.button :submit, "Submit", class: "button right tiny radius"
```

In my Controller:

```
 respond_to :json,  only: [:create_agent_confirmation]     

    def create_agent_confirmation
 if @agent_confirm.validate(params[:agent_confirm])
    @agent_confirm.save
    render ajax_redirect_to(root_path)
  else
    respond_with(@agent_confirm, status: :unprocessable_entity)
  end
end
```

My Coffescript:

```
$(document).ready ->
 $(".ajax_form").on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
 $(".error").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

When I Check both of the checkboxes and submit the form, a record is created in my model but both checkbox values are set to false. The reason for this is (via Firebug) that the form gets posted with 4 attributes. 2 for each of my checkboxes, with the first value for each being false(This value is submitted to the db).

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: You can double check that params hash in your console where you run rails server.

Comment: @preciz , it is the console that led me to my conclusion above. The form posts 4 params in stead of the wanted 2. It posts 2 x TRUE and 2 x FALSE. Since the FALSE params are first, they are recorded in the database when I save the result.

Comment: This questions code in itself doesn't show what could be the problem.